# NullpointerException error while working with choiceBox and arrays

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to get two different choice box to work at the same time However I am getting a nullpointer error in the initialize method. which is kind of weird cuz I am trying to initialize what is in the choice box but the IDE is giving me a nullpointer exception.

this is my code

```
package application;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SampleController implements Initializable{
    
    public static piece PieceClicked = new piece();
    ArrayList <Integer> possibleMoves = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    ListView<Integer> listView = new ListView<Integer>();
    
    private int enemyLocation;
    private boolean valid = true;
    
    @FXML 
    ChoiceBox<String> inputPieceType, inputPieceAllience;
    
    String[] pieces = {"CANNON","CHARIOT","ELAPHANT","GENERAL","GUARD","HORSES","SOLDIERS"};
    String[] allience = {"GREEN","RED"};
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        inputPieceType.getItems().addAll(pieces);
        inputPieceAllience.getItems().addAll(allience);
        
        inputPieceType.setOnAction(this::setPiece);
        inputPieceAllience.setOnAction(this::setAllience);
    }
    
    public void setPiece(ActionEvent event) {
        PieceClicked.setPieceType(inputPieceType.getValue());
    }
    
    public void setAllience(ActionEvent event) {
        PieceClicked.setPieceAllience(inputPieceAllience.getValue());
    }
}
```

it is also telling me that I have an error in my main class at
`Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));`

my main class is this

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
            
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and the error message was this

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/owenpark/eclipse/java-2020-06/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/computerIA/computerScienceIA/bin/application/Sample.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2677)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3323)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3280)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3249)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3222)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3199)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3192)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2673)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.SampleController.initialize(SampleController.java:62)
    ... 25 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

what could I do to help with this?

edit:
my fxmlfile
this is the scene with all the choice boxes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="403.0" prefWidth="839.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="1.0" layoutY="2.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="837.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="310.0" fitWidth="312.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="45.0">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../../../../../../../../../Documents/computer%20science%20IA%20photos/thumb-data_illust_Jang_Gi_Pan_1440x1440.jpeg" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <VBox layoutX="443.0" layoutY="43.0" prefHeight="315.0" prefWidth="146.0">
               <children>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="location: " />
                  <TextField fx:id="input" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="piece: " />
                  <ChoiceBox fx:id="inputPieceType" prefWidth="150.0" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Allience: " />
                  <ChoiceBox fx:id="inputPieceAllience" prefWidth="150.0" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="enemy piece location: " />
                  <TextField fx:id="inputEnemyPieceLocation" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="146.0" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <Button layoutX="332.0" layoutY="52.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="33.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="22.0" fitWidth="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../../../../../../Documents/computer%20science%20IA%20photos/Green_King.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button layoutX="332.0" layoutY="91.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="33.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="22.0" fitWidth="26.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../../../../../../Documents/computer%20science%20IA%20photos/Green_Cha.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button layoutX="332.0" layoutY="133.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="33.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="21.0" fitWidth="25.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../../../../../../Documents/computer%20science%20IA%20photos/Green_Cannon.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button layoutX="332.0" layoutY="171.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="42.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="24.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../../../../../../Documents/computer%20science%20IA%20photos/green_Elephant.jpeg" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button layoutX="332.0" layoutY="214.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="42.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="37.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../../../../../../Documents/computer%20science%20IA%20photos/Green_Horse.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button layoutX="332.0" layoutY="255.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="42.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="67.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../../../../../../Documents/computer%20science%20IA%20photos/Green_Soldier.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button layoutX="332.0" layoutY="296.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="42.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="33.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../../../../../../Documents/computer%20science%20IA%20photos/Green_Guard.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Text layoutX="39.0" layoutY="56.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="1        2          3         4          5         6        7          8          9" wrappingWidth="270.7308011274751" />
            <Text layoutX="29.0" layoutY="72.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="1" wrappingWidth="8.67726926690625" />
            <Text layoutX="29.0" layoutY="98.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="2" wrappingWidth="8.67726926690625" />
            <Text layoutX="29.0" layoutY="129.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="3" wrappingWidth="8.67726926690625" />
            <Text layoutX="27.0" layoutY="157.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="4" wrappingWidth="8.67726926690625" />
            <Text layoutX="27.0" layoutY="189.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="5" wrappingWidth="8.67726926690625" />
            <Text layoutX="29.0" layoutY="218.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="6" wrappingWidth="8.67726926690625" />
            <Text layoutX="29.0" layoutY="248.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="7" wrappingWidth="8.67726926690625" />
            <Text layoutX="29.0" layoutY="279.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="8" wrappingWidth="8.67726926690625" />
            <Text layoutX="29.0" layoutY="309.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="9" wrappingWidth="8.67726926690625" />
            <Text layoutX="22.0" layoutY="335.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="10" wrappingWidth="20.65190019321369" />
            <Button fx:id="enterButton" layoutX="452.0" layoutY="359.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#enterButton" text="Input" />
            <Button fx:id="clear" layoutX="516.0" layoutY="359.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clear" text="clear" />
            <Text layoutX="380.0" layoutY="72.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="GENERAL" />
            <Text layoutX="381.0" layoutY="110.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="CHARIOT" />
            <Text layoutX="382.0" layoutY="153.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="CANNON" />
            <Text layoutX="379.0" layoutY="189.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="ELEPHANT" />
            <Text layoutX="382.0" layoutY="234.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="HORSE" />
            <Text layoutX="382.0" layoutY="276.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="SOLDIER" />
            <Text layoutX="386.0" layoutY="317.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="GUARD" />
            <VBox layoutX="589.0" layoutY="42.0" prefHeight="317.0" prefWidth="126.0">
               <children>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="location:" />
                  <Label fx:id="locationCheck" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="126.0" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="piece Type: " />
                  <Label fx:id="pieceCheck" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="126.0" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Allience: " />
                  <Label fx:id="allianceCheck" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="128.0" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="enemy piece location:" />
                  <Label fx:id="enemyLocationCheck" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="127.0" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="error message:" wrappingWidth="123.269287109375" />
                  <Label fx:id="errorMessage" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="129.0" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <Text layoutX="607.0" layoutY="28.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="validity check" />
            <Text layoutX="723.0" layoutY="27.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Possible Possition" />
            <Text layoutX="710.0" layoutY="301.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="can this piece be taken" />
            <Label fx:id="PieceTake" layoutX="708.0" layoutY="305.0" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="126.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <ListView fx:id="listView" layoutX="715.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="248.0" prefWidth="113.0" />
      <Button fx:id="exitButton" layoutX="779.0" layoutY="361.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exitButton" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="47.0" text="exit" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

sample.fxml file is a different scene and basically it is just a starting scene where the user can choose between two different scenes to go to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
   <children>
      <Text layoutX="143.0" layoutY="53.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="welcome to janggi!">
         <font>
            <Font size="40.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Button fx:id="gameButton" layoutX="205.0" layoutY="85.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#gameButton" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="190.0" text="Game Play">
         <font>
            <Font size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="explanationButton" layoutX="205.0" layoutY="225.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#explanationButton" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="190.0" text="Explanation">
         <font>
            <Font size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Well, what is line 62 in SampleController.java?

Comment: (As an aside, I'd *strongly* encourage you to start following Java naming conventions.)

Comment: Ok sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: line 62 is ```inputPieceType.getItems().addAll(pieces);```

Comment: [mcve] please .. including the fxml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**:
The actual problem was that `SampleController` was linked to two different `.fxml` files and only the `Sample.fxml` file was being loaded, which didn't contain the `ChoiceBox`es. This can be fixed by having two separate controllers, one for each `.fxml` file, and loading them both.

**Old answer**:
In JavaFX controllers, fields marked with the `@FXML` tag have their values injected by the JavaFX-runtime from the controls defined in the `.fxml` file associated with the controller.

In your case, you've got two `ChoiceBox<String>` instances in the controller, so you'll need two `ChoiceBox`es defined in your `.fxml`-file as well. To allow the runtime to know which control to link to which field in the controller, you'll need to add an `fx:id="fieldName"` on each of the controls in the `.fxml` file. Don't forget to change the value from `fieldName` to the corresponding name of the field in the controller, in your case `inputPieceType` on one of them and `inputPieceAllience` on the other.

The `.fxml` file would then look something like this:

```
<ChoiceBox fx:id="inputPieceType" [other properties...] />
```

If you are unsure if the controller class is connected to your `.fxml` file, one way you can see this is by looking for the `fx:controller="com.example.MyController"` property inside of your `.fxml` file. The `com.example.MyController` will be the full name of the controller class, which in your case should be `application.SampleController`.

Note that you can also set the controller in code instead of in `.fxml` by calling `fxmlLoader.setController(controller);` when loading the `.fxml` file. Which one you use depends on your use case.

Comment: hello so I did check my fxml files and it does have all the required things
`<ChoiceBox fx:id="inputPieceType" prefWidth="150.0" />`
but I am still getting the same error

Comment: and normally if what you have stated was an issue wouldn't I run into an error when I tried to do something with the choiceBox? in my case I am running into an error right from the beginning when I start running the code.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly then you're getting a NPE on the line containing `inputPieceType.getItems().addAll(pieces);` which would mean that either `inputPieceType` is null, or the result of `.getItems()` is. I assumed it was the former, maybe it isn't?

Comment: Looking at the error message again, JavaFX is having trouble loading your `application/Sample.fxml` file. Could you add the entirety of that file to your question so we could take a look at it as well?

Comment: but how could the results of `.getItems()` be null aren't I just populating the choice box with the array `pieces`?

Comment: Yeah it seems strange, so that probably isn't what's going on here. Could you add the `Sample.fxml` code to your question in an edit?

Comment: yep I have just done that but sorry my fxml files might be a bit of a mess.
Oh and also when I remove the choice box from my controller the code runs fine. So I don't think there is an issue with the `sample.FXML` alone

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors, but maybe it doesn't like that the choicebox is closed immediately with an `/>`. Try changing the choicebox to be opened like this: `<ChoiceBox>
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Test value" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ChoiceBox>`

Comment: Oh, I see the issue now. You've got two different `.fxml` files. In the main class you are loading `Sample.fxml` but you've got your `ChoiceBox`es in another file, so you'll need to change it from `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));` to `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("[NAME OF OTHER FILE].fxml"));`

Comment: You need two different controllers for the two different `.fxml` files, you can't use the same for both as they contain different controls.

Comment: thank you soooooo much for your time and effort. I really appreciate it. The word becomes a better place because of people like you

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help! I'll go ahead and edit my answer to match what actually resolved the issue. Which was that you're using the same controller for two `.fxml` files, right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your .fxml file which you are loading in main method is on correct path (classpath).
2. If you verified, then please make sure variable names you declared in controller with @FXML annotation
   @FXML
   ChoiceBox inputPieceType, inputPieceAllience;
   are same or no typo in .fxml file by comparing it. If it does not match then javafx will unable to autowire ChoiceBox class in Controller and resulting null pointer exception.
3. Just a suggestion whenever you make changes(UI Components) using Scene Builder please refresh your .fxml files since eclipse sometimes take time to refresh it.

Answer (score -3):

The issue is that you never say `new ChoiceBox<String>`, so when you reference them with `inputPieceType.getItems().addAll(pieces);` or `inputPieceAllience.getItems().addAll(allience);` on line 62 they are calling methods for an item that was never created.

You could do something like this to initialize the objects:

```java
...
    private int enemyLocation;
    private boolean valid = true;
    
    @FXML 
    ChoiceBox<String> inputPieceType = new ChoiceBox<String>();
    @FXML
    ChoiceBox<String> inputPieceAllience = new ChoiceBox<String>();
    
    String[] pieces = {"CANNON","CHARIOT","ELAPHANT","GENERAL","GUARD","HORSES","SOLDIERS"};
    String[] allience = {"GREEN","RED"};
...
```